# Not getting list of items in shared folders with Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I have tried to get the list of folders with Google Drive API in Python. I can get the list in my drive folders but I can not get the list of items of shared folders. I use GCP service account for credential and I already set the service account into shared folder. Anyone has solutions?? Should I use another parameter?? Thank you so much.

```
drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

folderId = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

query = f"parents = '{folderId}'"
response = drive.files().list(q=query,includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,supportsAllDrives=True).execute()

files = response.get('files')
nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

while nextPageToken:
    response = drive.files().list(q=query,includeItemsFromAllDrives=True,supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
    files.extend(response.get('files'))
    nextPageToken = response.get('nextPageToken')

df = pd.DataFrame(files)
```

Comment: if you shared the folder with the service account, just try doing a files.list without all the search params can you see the folder then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the way you are calling parents

```
query = f"parents = '{folderId}'"
```

Parents = should be parents **in**

```
query = f"parents in '{folderId}'"
```

## background info in the event you have the wrong file id for the folder.

Start simple when you are working with the Q parameter.  Can you find the folder by searching for the mimetype?

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'",
                                          
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

## Parents in

Assuming that you get the folder back in the previous call you need to take the file id of that call and send it to this call.

```
page_token = None
while True:
    response = drive_service.files().list(q="parents in 'FILEIDFROMPREVIOUSCALL'",
                                          
                                          fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
                                          pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for file in response.get('files', []):
        # Process change
        print 'Found file: %s (%s)' % (file.get('name'), file.get('id'))
    page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)
    if page_token is None:
        break
```

Comment: yes, it returns the list including folder info.

Comment: You need to use parents **in** not parents =  check my example.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail advice. I tried your code but it doesn't return anything with shared folder id. It returns only my-drive-contents.It seems to be authentications problem. I'm not sure though ......

Comment: I was able to know G-drive api more through your advices. I vote your comment , thank you so much.